# Print screen shot combination not working

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys, screenshot

I'm using windows 10.

I want to know how to fix print screen + windows key to save current screen.

Until yesterday, I was using PrtScr + windows key hotkey combination to

save current screen to picture folder.

It's not working now, I think it's after an window update.

I can still use PrtScr key alone, it saves current screen to clipboard.

List of hotkey combinations I tried:

- Windows key + PrtScn : not working
- Alt + Print Screen : not working
- Windows Key + Shift + S : working

Answer (score -1):

Download and use 'PowerToys' (free utility), then you can remap keys and create any shortcut combinations you like.

Its open source but was developed by Microsoft.

https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys/releases/

Comment: Using a 3rd party tool to fix a generic Windows feature isn't an answer, IMHO.

Comment: You are incorrect, its not a 3rd party tool, its a Microsoft tool, I already mentioned that in my answer.

Follow this link if you have any further questions.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/

Comment: not working. Assigned prtscr to ctrl prtscr and didn't work.

Comment: @EricLee Ok clearly something wrong. To test the screen save function, go to 'Windows settings > Ease of access'. In navigation pane, scroll down list and click on 'Keyboard'. In main pane, scroll down to 'Print Screen shortcut' and turn the slider 'On'.
Now, to see if the system will do a screen save, press the 'Prtscr' key. The screen will go darker and some buttons will appear at the top of the screen. 
One of them is 'Fullscreen clip', hover mouse to find which one, click that.
Now the system should save the screen as it would do for the Windows key + PrtScr combination.